# Как вставить индекс на каждый скролл?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

Как вставить индекс на каждый скролл? Как можно сделать чтобы добавляется индекс

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: -200 });
        } else {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 200 });
        }
    });
});
```

> Например вниз 200 400 600 800 вверх 800 600 400 200

**UPDATE**

[Пример](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  function d() {
    b = !1
  }
  var b = !1;
  $(window).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll", function(c) {
    c.preventDefault();
    if (!b) {
      b = !0;
      var a = $(this).scrollTop() / 200 | 0,
        a = 200 * a + (0 <= (parseInt(c.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -c.originalEvent.detail)) ? -200 : 200);
      -200 > a || a > $("html").height() + 200 - $(window).height() ? b = !1 : $("html, body")
        .not(":animated").animate({
          scrollTop: a
        }, 800, "swing", d)
    }
  })
});
```

```css
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 article {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 4em;
   line-height: 2.6em;
 }
 article:nth-child(2n) {
   background: #FFCC00;
   color: #FFFFFF;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="article-post">01</article>
<article class="article-post">02</article>
<article class="article-post">03</article>
<article class="article-post">04</article>
<article class="article-post">05</article>
<article class="article-post">06</article>
<article class="article-post">07</article>
<article class="article-post">08</article>
<article class="article-post">09</article>
<article class="article-post">10</article>
<article class="article-post">11</article>
<article class="article-post">12</article>
<article class="article-post">13</article>
<article class="article-post">14</article>
<article class="article-post">15</article>
<article class="article-post">16</article>
<article class="article-post">17</article>
<article class="article-post">18</article>
<article class="article-post">19</article>
<article class="article-post">20</article>
<article class="article-post">21</article>
```

скролл по блочно ... может вам плагин **fullPage** и использовать?

Comment: скролл вверх не работает

Comment: немного поправил код, если снова не работает, напишите ваш браузер

Comment: @рони спасибо вам!